# Python 3: Geopandas dataframe with CRS coordinates into Graph to find connected components and other graph properties?

Tags: python-3.x, graph-theory, geopandas, connected-components

I have a geopandas dataframe where I find to use some graph theory package to find graph properties such as connected components.

**How can I find graph-theoretic properties conveniently with Geopandas dataframe?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pysal` to generate spatial weights matrix (which is internally graph) - http://pysal.org/notebooks/lib/libpysal/weights.html. All weights classes have `from_dataframe` option.

Spatial weights can be further exported to `networkx` Graph object for further graph-based analysis.

```py
import libpysal
import geopandas

df = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

W = libpysal.weights.Queen.from_dataframe(df)  # generate spatial weights

G = W.to_networkx() # get networkx.Graph
```

Notice that for some of the things (like components), you can use weights directly - see attributes in docs https://pysal.org/libpysal/generated/libpysal.weights.W.html#libpysal.weights.W.

Comment: can you provide a small working example to make this more reproducible for future? Pysal looks promising +1, something like below?

```import pysal
import libpysal
import geopandas
from libpysal.weights import Queen, Rook, KNN
import networkx

gdf = myDF
w_rook = Rook.from_dataframe(gdf)
...
(graph to network)
...
ntw.network_fully_connected
ntw.network_n_components
```

Comment: I have added some example, but if you need something more specific you should open a specific question.

Comment: @hhh generally the burden of the small working example falls to the asker, not the answerer